# How do I set the database password for pg_prove in PgTAP?

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, automated-tests, rdbms, pgtap

Just getting started with pgTAP, I'm using a localhost running docker container server. How do I tell pgTAP what the password for that server is? I don't see anything mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PgTAP `pg_prove` respects the [PostgreSQL Environment Vars](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html), so you need to set `PGPASSWORD` in the environment before running. Since `pg_prove` runs using `psql` I suspect you can also set a `~/.pgpass`.